# Setting Form to CenterParent when main form is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that I want to show centred to its parent, using something like this.

```
  Form f = new Form();     
  f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
  f.ShowDialog(this);
```

The problem occurs if this code is triggered whilst the application is in a minimised state and when the application is restored my form is shown at the top right of the screen, rather than being centred to its parent.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

The Standard Windows MessageBox Dialog behaves correctly and when the application is restored from the minimised state, the dialog box is in the correct position.

Comment: are you calling `f` from other thread?

Comment: @jonathana No..

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to "cache" the parent form location when its being minimized
 (overriding `WndProc()` method will let the ability to cache the form location **before** its being minimized).

```
private Point CachedLocation;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x0112) // WM_SYSCOMMAND
    {
        if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0xF020)) // SC_MINIMIZE
        {
            // save the form location beofore it is minimized
               CachedLocation= this.Location;
        }
        m.Result = new IntPtr(0);
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Now, if the parent form is minimized when calling the child form use the Cached location point (by checking `FormWindowState` Enum):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    Form f = new Form();
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        f.Top = (CachedLocation.Y + (this.Height / 2)) - f.Height / 2;
        f.Left = (CachedLocation.X + (this.Width / 2)) - f.Width / 2;

        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: The FormsLocation function doesn't look necessary.  Aren't the parameters reversed?  X is usually left, Y is usually top.

Comment: @LarsTech `WndProc()` is calling `FormsLocation`, about the reversed parameters i did not understand what do you mean(?), OP want to to locate the child form in the center of the parent.

Comment: Yes, but it could also just be `CachedLocation = this.Location;`  About the reversed parameters, X is considered the horizontal position, Y is the vertical position.  You do it the other way around for some reason.

Comment: I agree with you that `CachedLocation = this.Location` can replace `FormsLocation` (but the basic idea of solution was given), also now i get what you mean about the parameters...yes you are right i did not test i it and now i see the mistake, few minuets i will fix this (part of it i did from my smartphone)). thank you!!

Comment: This almost works, but it looks like I need to also keep a copy of the original Size as well as location.

Comment: Why do you have the line `m.Result = new IntPtr(0);` ? I would have thought that I should **not** be changing anything in the current message.

Comment: @sgmoore as far a i know `m.Result = new IntPtr(0);` is used for house keeping but it is not a must. MSDN: "If an application processes this message, it should return zero to continue creation of the window. If the application returns –1, the window is destroyed". also i guess you know you can do `CachedSize = this.Size;` but  why do you need to keep a copy of the size? i have been struggling with similar problem like that in the past and that was the only solution i could think about, if you will find other solution i will be happy if you share it.